# Passing props from one component to another when the transition happens using router.push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have a Vue.js component called `Summoner.vue` which is rendered thanks to the router when a user visits the following URL - `http://localhost:8080/summoner/username`

In that component I have a `<div>` element which triggers a method on click, that sends the user to a new URL - `http://localhost:8080/summoner/username/match/4132479262` which renders a different component `Match.vue`. Like this:

```
<div @click='specificMatch(match.gameId)'>

specificMatch(gameId){
    router.push('/summoner/' + this.summoner + '/match/' + gameId)
}
```

Now all I want to do is pass an object as props from the first component to the second one, but I'm not sure how to do that because I'm using the router. Normally I'd pass props like this - `<summoner v-bind:match="match.id"></summoner>` but I guess that doesn't work in my case since I'm using router.

And these are my routes:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/summoner/:summonerName',
        name: 'summoner',
        component: Summoner
    },
    {
        path: '/summoner/:summonerName/match/:matchId',
        name: 'match',
        component: Match
    }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with `vue-router` props :

```js
 {
        path: '/summoner/:summonerName',
        name: 'summoner',
        component: Summoner,
        props : true // now you can pass props to this route
    }
```

then when you want to navigate to it :

```js
this.$router.push({ name : summoner , params : { summonerName : this.summoner , somedata : 'hello'  etc ... }})
```

now summoner component will have access to all these params on its props :

```js
// summoner.vue

export default {
  props : ['somedata',...]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!